# How to insert the query data inside the data object while doing map in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
      router.get("/getCompanies", async (req, res) => {
    
      try {
        let comapanies = [];
        const comapanies_data = await Company.find({}).exec();
        await comapanies_data.forEach(async (company) => {
    
          let data = {}
          const companyId = ObjectID(company._id)
    
          Company.find({ _id: companyId })
            .exec((err, company) => {
              console.log(company)
              data['company'] = { company };
            });
    
          Project.find({ company: companyId })
            .populate('Board')
            .exec((err, Project) => {
              data['projects'] = { Project };
            });
    
          Member.find({ company: companyId })
            .exec((err, Member) => {
              data['members'] = { Member };
            });
    
          Subscription.find({ company: companyId })
            .exec((err, Subscription) => {
              data['subscription'] = { Subscription };
            });
          comapanies.push(...data)
        })
        return res.status(200).json(comapanies)
    
      }
      catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ err })
      }

});
```

data is not inserted the data object, I want to send all the data together in an array of name companies can anyone find out please why the company, project, member, and subscription data is not inserting in the data object

Comment: `data` is an object so you can't do `comapanies.push(...data)`. Try to change it for `comapanies.push(data)`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Have you checked the `companyId` variable to see if it is valid? I can't see where are you importing `ObjectID` from.

Comment: yeah its valid, i have console loged

Comment: Is this `console.log(company)` showing every company in the forEach?